# "Lock to launcher" - icon disappears after OS restart

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I mounted a second drive (automount) labeled zdrive. Using Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 as client on VirtualBox (windows host).

I extracted PhpStorm on to the zdrive and start it in bash using ~/zdrive/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh

When Phpstorm starts I click the icon in the launcher bar and select "Lock to Launcher".

When i restart the OS, the icon is no longer locked to the launcher.  Is there a way to persist the icon to the launcher?